# need help compiling something! (:

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm helping the developers of a IM test their security and issues, and they wanted a example of the tcp reset vulnerability reported on their server. I'm having issues compiling it, can someone help? 
Error log:
http://pastie.org/4212921

C file:
http://www.exploit-db.com/download/291

Comment: Can you post your relevant code and error message here? If it's too huge, can you try for [smaller example that shows the problem](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: it outputs a lot of errors sadly /: so i cant really create a small example

Comment: Did you compile it according to the instructions in the C file? Did you install libnet properly?

Comment: yes , both have been done, verified libnet.a's existance also

Comment: how about: `** be sure to modify the MAC addresses (enet_src/enet_dst) in the code, or you WILL have problems!` ?

Comment: i did that , unless i did it wrong

Comment: truct libnet_ether_addr *ptr_enet_src;
u_char enet_src[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX];
u_char enet_dst[192.168.1.1];
u_char org_code[3] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

Comment: @user1478935, your question title is very much sub-standard. Please edit it to be more specific. Imagine everybody posting her or his questions with titles like that one.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost always a good idea to start with the first reported error.

In your cases, the first reported error is:

```
reset-tcp.c:51: error: ‘u_char’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

`u_char` is not a standard C type; it's probably a typedef for `unsigned char`.

Your source file has the following `#include` directives:

```
#include <libnet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

`<stdio.h>` can't define `u_char`, so it must be defined in `<libnet.h>` -- specifically in whatever version of `<libnet.h>` the source file depends on.

That's a non-standard header (it's not installed on my system), so my best guess is that you're using a different version of libnet than the one `reset-tcp.c` was designed to work with.

I know that doesn't solve your problem, but it should give you a good starting point.

**EDIT :**

I just installed the `libnet1`, `libnet1-dev`, and `libnet1-doc` packages on my Ubuntu 12.04 system (version 1.1.4-2.1 of `libnet1`). Your source file now compiles (after joining lines 74 and 75) with some warnings. The type `u_char` is defined in `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/types.h`, which is indirectly included by `libnet.h`.

I do get some warnings:

```
291.c:95:1: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘u_char *’ [-Wformat]
291.c:95:1: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 4 has type ‘u_char *’ [-Wformat]
291.c:95:1: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 5 has type ‘u_char *’ [-Wformat]
291.c:95:1: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 6 has type ‘u_char *’ [-Wformat]
291.c:95:1: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 7 has type ‘u_char *’ [-Wformat]
291.c:95:1: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 8 has type ‘u_char *’ [-Wformat]
291.c:116:1: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
```

which you should definitely pay attention to; the code currently tries to store `int` values in `u_char` (`unsigned char`) objects.

**Suggestions :**

1. Tell us what operating system and what version of `libnet` you're using; someone may be able to offer better advice if we have this information.
2. Let us know where that source code came from, and see if you can find out what version of `libnet` it's supposed to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `libnet` and its developement package.

Under Debian you do this by installing the packages `libnet1` and `libnet-dev`.